# HTML Email Signature Display Issues

Tags: email, html-email, thunderbird, electronic-signature

So, I have created an email signature and am testing it in Thunderbird.  I am using thunderbird because they provide the easiest way of testing new signatures (just paste and go.)

However, I am finding that after I REPLY sometimes the images show up IN the email itself as

`<my-image-name.gif>` or sometimes they show up as

`<mime-attachment.png>`

This only happens on a reply, BUT it does show up this way on both the iPhone and Thunderbird..  Initially everything looks fine.

No, none of the images are missing.  As mentioned, the signature looks great on initial send.

Wondering is there any meta-data info. I need to put in the beginning of the signature besides `<html><body>`?  I think the email programs are jacking with the html in the signature.  Is there a way to prevent it?  Or is it something else entirely going on here?

Comment: Markdown considers `<` and `>` to be HTML that it's supposed to render, so I had to use some back-ticks to get this to look right.  If my edit differs from your intent, please correct it (or comment here and I'll give it another try).

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some code so we can see what's going on.  Also, are the images present as intended when you view the message later from your Sent folder?

Comment: Thanks @Adam.  Much appreciate the response.  So, it looks like this is only happening, actually, if I reply from the iPhone?  And yes, in the sent folder on my iPhone they are messed up.  However, the email is showing up in my iPhone's SENT folder, but not on my desktop which seems odd since it's IMAP.  Maybe there is an iPhone email setting that affects this, but I can't see one.